# decompile aspx pages generated using precompilation tool

Tags: c#, asp.net, telerik, decompiling, decompiler

I have a compiled code it is asp.net web forms application. I have decompiled its code using Telerik JustDecompiler and .NetRefactor. I am unable to decompile ASPX pages. I have file App_Web_login.aspx.cdcab7d2.dll which has following view if decompiled using justdecompile 
[image]

However, ASPX pages have text

```
This is a marker file generated by the precompilation tool, and should not be deleted!
```

Can anyone guide me how to decompile these aspx pages?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Answer is ***no***. You cannot decompile them back to original ASPX pages using tool.

If you decompile them, you will get the code like this -

```
private HtmlHead __BuildControl__control2()
{
  HtmlHead htmlHead = new HtmlHead("head");
  HtmlTitle htmlTitle = this.__BuildControl__control3();
  IParserAccessor parserAccessor = (IParserAccessor) htmlHead;
  parserAccessor.AddParsedSubObject((object) htmlTitle);
  HtmlLink htmlLink = this.__BuildControl__control4();
  parserAccessor.AddParsedSubObject((object) htmlLink);
  return htmlHead;
}
```

From then, you will have to reassemble ASPX page manually by looking at two files - rendered HTML *inside browser* and above C# code.